# How to save data from html form in a csv file in angular

Tags: angular

i have a form with two fields one for email and another for phone.
i need to append the data from these fields into a csv file, so that we can send notification to the users who have opted for notification once the website is live. how can i do this in angularjs.

i am confused about if i have to upload csv file first or how and where the csv file will be saved and all. i am UI developer and not sure if this task will be performed on frontend on backend.

my boss is saying this is supposed to be frontend job.

Comment: this not frontend job, its backend job, you can read & modify files in server, can't do that at clientside

Comment: @Webinion CSV files are plain text files. He can. As for the OP, please tell us if you use Angular or AngularJS, and change the tags accordingly.

Comment: @Webinion: well, they could download the whole database, edit it, and reupload, but they or rather their boss would deserve to be thrown out of the next window for that...


SushmitGaur: your boss is either lying or stupid (most likely the latter in my experience). the way to go is: your frontend sends the form (as a POST request, like any other web form) to the backend, there it's validated/etc and saved into the "database" (btw, csv is one of the worst storages for stuff like that, try to convince him of using a real database system; or stuff will become horribly slow horribly soon).

Comment: `your boss is either lying or stupid (most likely the latter in my experience).`

Hahahaha lol.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in angular. check out this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-csv. You should probably get some idea after seeing this. Otherwise you can just write a plain javascript function to write data to CSV. There are many examples.

The file gets downloaded to the default downloads folder in you PC.